# How to use nested action event in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a flight reservation system project. My concern is about nested action listener event. I mean my button is event is dependent on another.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == b1) 
    {
        r1.setVisible(true);
        r2.setVisible(true);
        r3.setVisible(true);
        r4.setVisible(true);
        if(ae.getsource()==r1)
        {
            -------
            -------
        }
    }
}
```

here when I am pressing my button `b1` thereafter only I am able to press my `r1` button but the second if condition is not working.

Please let me know how to use nested action events.

Comment: Why don't you disable your second `JButton` by default, and enable it only after you have pressed the 1st one. However, it's hard to understand what you want to do, then, please post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will cause less confusion, more, faster and better answers to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ae.getSource()` will only ever equals either b1 or r1 (or something else).  It won't both equal b1 and r1 at the same time, so your nested condition will never be reached.  If r1 won't be visible until b1 is clicked, then this is probably all you need.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
        r1.setVisible(true);
        r2.setVisible(true);
        r3.setVisible(true);
        r4.setVisible(true);
    } else if (ae.getSource() == r1) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a variable to store some state about when r1 can react to a button press.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == b1) {
        r1ready = true;
    } else if (ae.getSource() == r1) {
        if (r1ready) {
          // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class level variable to keep track of whether the b1 button had been pressed, or I would add the event handler method call to the r1 button from inside the b1 buttons event handler. This depends on what the functionality of the r1 button would be if the b1 button had not been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, if the source is r1 then the inner "if" will never be executed because the outer "if" will have been false. What you probably want is something like:

```
  Object src = ae.getSource();
  if ( src == b1 ) {
     // handle clicke in b1
  } else if ( src == r1 ) {
     // handle clicks in r1
  }
```